# why data is not processed in RichFlatMapFunction

Tags: apache-flink

In order to improve the performance of data process, we store events to a map and do not process them untill event count reaches 100.
in the meantime, start a timer in open method, so data is processed every 60 seconds

this works when flink version is **1.11.3**,

after upgrading flink version to **1.13.0**

I found sometimes events were consumed from Kafka continuously, but were not processed in RichFlatMapFunction, it means data was missing.
after restarting service, it works well, but several hours later the same thing happened again.

any known issue for this flink version? any suggestions are appreciated.

```
public class MyJob {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ...
        DataStream<String> rawEventSource = env.addSource(flinkKafkaConsumer);
        ...
    }
```

```
public class MyMapFunction extends RichFlatMapFunction<String, String> implements Serializable {

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        ...
        long periodTimeout = 60;
        pool.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            // processing data
        }, periodTimeout, periodTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void flatMap(String message, Collector<String> out) {
        // store event to map 
        // count event, 
        // when count = 100, start data processing
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you ensure that the count will always reac 100? Did you add a debug line to chech it? Maybe it is the reason. It is why a counter is not a good idea to start some processing on an unpredictable stream of events. I would prefer to rely on a counter together with a timer. Or a simple timer, process window time, will offer a predictable result

Comment: we want to access DB with bulk insert request to improve performance, so this is why need a counter. in the meantime, still need a timer to trigger data process each minute to avoid data latency.
will add a debug line to check count. Felipe, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid doing things with user threads and timers in Flink functions. The supported mechanism for this is to use a KeyedProcessFunction with processing time timers.

Comment: will try to use native way KeyedProcessFunction to refactor code. many thanks to you, David.